# How to count lines of specified file on multiple machines using python?

Tags: python

Say I have two machines A and B, I want to count the lines specified file on each machine and sum up on machine C. Is there some wonderful solutions for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this too broad a question to ask? Could you show us some part of a solution that you are already working on?

Please also specify the language version more clearly i.e. Python2.x or 3.x.